# Force equal margin in gtable plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, margins, gtable

I want to plot a grid of plots of equal size with gtable. I first create a list of plot for each row and then combine the column with:

```
col_list = list()
for (j in c(1:n_col)){
  col_list[[j]] = do.call(rbind, c(row_list[[j]], size="last"))
}
g = do.call(cbind, c(col_list, size="last"))
grid.draw(g)
```

where each `row_list` contains a `ggplotGrob` plot. Some plots have conditional formatting for titles and x axis label.

unfortunately, when plotting the image I have the bottom plots squeezed:

[image]

Thanks!